# PHP 7.2 can not connect IIS ODBC

Tags: php, mysql, odbc

Structure :

IP A : IIS 6.2 (Windows 2012) ODBC DSN connect to IP B Myssql

IP B : Mysql 5.6

---

IP A set ODBC for classic ASP and PHP use

- classic ASP can connect
- PHP 7.2 **can not** connect

---

This is my PHP code :

```
try{
    $conn = new PDO ("odbc:myDSN");

    die(json_encode(array('outcome' => true)));
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
     die(json_encode(array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect')));
};
```

**RESULT :** {"outcome":false,"message":"Unable to connect"}

This is my classic ASP code :

```
<%
    Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set cmconn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        cmconn.Open "dsn=myDSN;Stmt=Set Names 'UTF-8';"
    Set cmrs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        SQL = "SELECT * FROM members Where id = 1"
        cmrs.open sql,cmconn,1,1
      if not cmrs.Eof or not cmrs.Bof Then
          response.Write( cmrs("name") )
      else
          response.Write("error")
      end if
      cmrs.close
%>
```

**RESULT :** no problem